# Epub file with two columns

Tags: html, css, epub, ibooks

Can any one suggest me epub files which are having two columns in it.I am having a problem in making two columns in css file.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [MobileRead](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=55347) thread. A couple of things to mention:

1. .epub files work on a variety of readers, some of which are on *really small* screens. You might want to steer away from multiple columns unless you know the reader is not going to be on a smartphone.
2. There are also a couple CSS3 styles you can poke at here: [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html). Be sure to test things out on a variety of readers -- some readers don't support the latest CSS (or any CSS at all).

Comment: I want to make a bilingual book, so my content are in two columns format. In the left the original and in the right the translation, and I think that is a good solution that do not lock the font size or page layout as a table would it.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally multiple columns is not something you should be trying to do in an ebook. You should leave it up to the reading device/software, which may (or may not) provide that kind of functionality to the end-user. For instance, Readium has a two-column mode.

Comment: I do agree with that, and I should add that columns do not play well if a page break occurs in the middle of them. For example, neither iBooks nor Readium do manage to stop the columning at the bottom of the first page and restart it at the top of the second page, resulting in a broken reading order.